# Replacing to single Blackslash adds " in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, escaping

I am trying to replace the character `!` to `\` in Qt but while doing this it adds an extra `"` which is very difficult to work around with.

I have a raw data something like this:
`"\"v=0\\r\\no=- 1534195387162130326 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\\r\\ns=-\\r\\nt=0 0\\r\\na=group:BUNDLE audio video\\r\\na=msid-semantic: WMS\\r\\nm=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 102 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126...` and I want the data to be like this: `"v=0\r\no=- 6804998800185322649 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=group:BUNDLE audio video\r\na=msid-semantic: WMS\r\nm=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 102 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126...`

So, my implementation is something like this:

```
data.replace("\\", "!");
data.remove("\"");
data.replace("!", "\"");
```

It is running as expected till the `remove` but after that it adds extra `"` and the output which I am eventually getting is:
`"v=0\"r\"no=- 757357016964659282 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\"r\"ns=-\"r\"nt=0 0\"r\"na=group:BUNDLE audio video\"r\"na=msid-semantic: WMS\"r\"nm=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 102 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126...`.

Any idea to work around will be great.

Comment: `data.replace("!", "\"");` does not it already tell to add `"` instead of `!`

Comment: Well that is the way around to go with the single backslash, otherwise the code won't compile.

Comment: How do you print your strings?

Comment: I am working on Visual Studio and putting a breakpoint and then looking at the value. I also printed the value using qInfo() to see if this is only visual but that is not the case. The results are same.

Comment: So, you're absolutely sure that Qt add-in for Visual Studio doesn't escape the string values for display? I'd bet it does. I think that you're fighting imaginary issues. Have a look at the contents of the string using a memory view, or use `Q_ASSERT` on known string positions, or dump the string to a file, etc. Most likely you're facing behavior similar to that of `QDebug`, and the debugging environment escapes things for you. **It is false that the substitution you're using adds any extra characters. Period.**

Answer (score 1):

It seems, you are not asking about replacing `!` with `\` but to remove double backslashes and escaped quotation marks from your string.

You could achieve this with the following two lines:

```
data.remove("\\\""); // remove \"
data.replace("\\\\", "\\"); // replace \\ with \
```

Comment: I tried that already and that gives me output as:
`"v=0\\r\\no=- 651392959210462988 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\\r\\ns=-\\r\\nt=0 0\\r\\na=group:BUNDLE audio video\\r\\na=msid-semantic: WMS\\r\\nm=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 102 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126...` which is one extra ` \ `.

Comment: Seems like its the same problem with stackoverflow `\`, doesn't work.

Comment: @PrashantDey So you are actually not asking about replacing `!` with `\` but to remove `\\` from your string. I edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: The part where I have \" is to be removed and where I have \\ is to be replaced with single backslash \. You can see the input and the desired output in my question.

Comment: @PrashantDey Yes, I got it. Please revisit my edited answer. Also consider to rephrase your question accordingly.

Comment: I tried this new one but now the output is same as the input string.

Comment: @PrashantDey Okay, you got me, I should have tested this ;-) It seems to be trickier than expected, because QString does some internal escaping when creating and printing the string.

Comment: @StanleyF. **QString does not alter its contents haphazardly.** `QString` does no escaping! Printing of the string is done e.g. by `qDebug` and there, sure, there is escaping done just so that it's possible to read the contents unambiguously. For output without such escaping, dump the string to a plain-text `QLabel`, or into `QTextStream(stdout)` or somesuch. **Do not mistake debug output quoting for what it isn't!**

Answer (score 0):

You're conflating debug output, which most debugging environments proffer with C-like escaping applied, with contents of the string. Remember that you can assert what's in the string without any ambiguity. To wit:

```
#include <QtCore>
int main() {
  //         01234567 89AB
  QString s("abc!def\\ghi\"");
  auto const originalSize = s.size();
  Q_ASSERT(originalSize == (3*3 + 3)); // three 3-letter groups, and three punctuation characters
  Q_ASSERT(!s.startsWith('\"')); // doesn't start with a quote
  Q_ASSERT(s.startsWith('a'));
  Q_ASSERT(s[3] == '!');
  Q_ASSERT(s[7] == '\\');
  Q_ASSERT(s[11] == '\"');
  s.replace('!', '\\');
  Q_ASSERT(s.size() == originalSize); // the size hasn't changed 
  Q_ASSERT(s[3] == '\\');
  qDebug() << s;
}
```

You can use this example to play with string contents to prove to yourself that you understand what is happening. Note that the debug output will look as follows, in spite of there being no additional quotes in the string.

```
"abc\\def\\ghi\""
```